# How to concatenate all items in an Observable Array using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the folowing object:

```
var Transaction = function (data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.transaction.ID);
    this.number = ko.observable(data.transaction.number);
    this.userID = ko.observable(data.transaction.userID);
    this.password = ko.observable(data.transaction.password);

    this.Properties = ko.observableArray(data.Property);
}
```

The Properties observable array looks like this(in JSON):

```
[{"address1":"111 Broadway","city":"Brooklyn","state":"NY","zip":null},
{"address1":"222 Broadway","city":"Brooklyn","state":"NY","zip":null}]
```

In my HTML I have something like this:

```
<span>PROPERTY</span>
<span data-bind="foreach: Properties">
<span data-bind="text: address1"></span>
<span data-bind="text: city"></span>
span data-bind="text: state"></span>
<span data-bind="text: zip"></span>
</span>
```

In the browser it looks like:

```
PROPERTY 
111 Broadway 
Brooklyn 
NY 
222 Broadway
Brooklyn 
NY
```

And I want it to look like:

```
111 Broadway, Brooklyn, NY 
222 Broadway, Brooklyn, NY
```

Any advice?

Comment: seems your spans are being styled as block elements. what's your stylesheet look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a computed property in the `Transaction` prototype as the `Properties` *list view*, which would simplify the HTML markup associated with it.

```js
this.propertyView = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.Properties().map(function(prop) {
    var singleProp = '';
    for (var p in prop)
      if (prop[p])
        singleProp += prop[p] + ', ';
    return singleProp.slice(0,-2);
  });
}, this);
```

```html
<span>PROPERTIES</span>
<!-- ko foreach: propertyView -->
<p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly, thanks a lot! Just another little question- how can I get rid of the null values? now it looks like this: 111 Broadway, Brooklyn, NY, null

222 Broadway, Brooklyn, NY, null

Comment: If you suggest using `for..in`, don't forget to use `hasOwnProperty` as well. OP could include the not-null condition from previous comment in the same `if` statement.

Comment: @user3378165 I've updated my answer to do just that :) . @Jeroen, I'm curious as to how `prop.hasOwnProperty(p) && prop[p]` is better than `prop[p]` in the if condition ? I don't think it matters here, do tell me if I missed a scenario..

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap those "foreached" properties in a block level element like a `p` or a `div` tag, e.g. like this:

```js
var Transaction = function (data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.transaction.ID);
    this.number = ko.observable(data.transaction.number);
    this.userID = ko.observable(data.transaction.userID);
    this.password = ko.observable(data.transaction.password);
    this.Properties = ko.observableArray(data.properties);
};

var vm = new Transaction({ 
  transaction: { ID: 1, number: 2,  userID: 3, password: 'secret' },
  properties: [{"address1":"111 Broadway","city":"Brooklyn","state":"NY","zip":null},
               {"address1":"222 Broadway","city":"Brooklyn","state":"NY","zip":null}]
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h1>
  <span data-bind="text: ID"></span> -
  <span data-bind="text: number"></span> -
  <span data-bind="text: userID"></span> -
  <span data-bind="text: password"></span>
</h1>
<span>PROPERTIES</span>
<!-- ko foreach: Properties -->
<p>
  <span data-bind="text: address1"></span>
  <span data-bind="text: city"></span>
  <span data-bind="text: state"></span>
  <span data-bind="text: zip"></span>
</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wanted to concatenate the values in the code rather than in the HTML. Thank you.